# when displaying the image in Crystal report background text is black Color

Tags: c#, css, vb.net, image, crystal-reports

i  written text on a picture by VB.NET after save picture to my pc is good but my issue  when displaying the image in Crystal report background text is black Color 
I want the background white writing

```
  On Error Resume Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg")
    PictureBox2.Image.Save(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    'End If
    Dim bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg")

    Dim newImage = New Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height + 40)

    Dim gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
    gr.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0)
    gr.DrawString(MigraID.Text & Space(2) & MigraName.Text & Space(2) & IqamaNum.Text & Space(2) & DatePicH.Text,
     New Font("Tahoma", 22),
    Brushes.Black, New RectangleF(0, bmp.Height, bmp.Width, 50))


    newImage.Save(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + MigraID.Text + ".jpg")

    PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + MigraID.Text + ".jpg")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: See [Why images in Crystal Report with white background doesn't show as pure white?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040517/why-images-in-crystal-report-with-white-background-doesnt-show-as-pure-white).

Comment: I did that but still the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

gr.Clear(Color.White)